# Set a default UNC path for QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to open QFileDialog with a specific path like: //Machine/C$/Users/. I have implemented the following function but it doesn't work.

```
void DownloadFM::on_pushButtonSource_clicked()
{
    QFileDialog o_dialogSource;
    o_dialogSource.setDirectory(absolutePath);
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Choose File");

    if(fileName.isEmpty())
        return;

    ui->lineEditSource->setText(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you want to open a dialog at desktop location do as follows:

```
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Choose File",QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation));
```

Please notice that you have to `#include <QStandardPaths>`

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
QFileDialog o_dialogSource;
o_dialogSource.setDirectory(absolutePath);
```

and this

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Choose File");
```

are completely independent. The former creates a local dialog object, sets the path in it, and... never shows the dialog. The latter creates *another* dialog—that does appear on the screen—passing the default value of the third argument as `const QString &dir=QString()` (see [this function documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName)), thus not setting the path you wanted.

The proper way is to remove the useless `o_dialogSource` lines, and then add the necessary argument to the `getOpenFileName` call:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Choose File", absolutePath);
```

Comment: @night-wolf does it open the directory if you manually enter your path in the dialog?

Comment: Yeah. I can open unc path manually in QFIleDialog but it doesn't show it by default.